# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'city' of 'adUnits' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error while trying to loop through my API response datas, what i'm i doing wrong? [Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTEQo.png)
Here is my code

```
  const fetchAdsunit = async () =>{

  const {data} = await axios.get(ADUINTS_API)


  for (const entry of Object.entries(data)) {

const latLong = await getLatLong(entry.adUnits)
    
    console.log(latLong); 
  }


}


  const getLatLong = async (adUnits) => {

    const { city, country, latitude, longitude, region, zip } = adUnits;
    const searchKey = [city, country, latitude, longitude, region, zip].filter([Boolean]).join().replaceAll(" ", "&")
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${searchKey}.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYXluZXJkIiwiYSI6ImNsNXd2d3dsNTBnbGczaXBzNDZsZHY3c3gifQ.D83CJ8cPbVnHimjcW0efNg`);

    return data
  }
```

Comment: It seems like your `adUnits` Object does not have a city property. Can you show an example of response from your API ?

Comment: payload:
adUnits: Array(2)
0:
asset:
aspectRatio: "16:9"
capability:
banner: true
video: true

Comment: Can you add it in the question ?